# struct instance as member of class in C#

Tags: c#, struct, stack, heap-memory

I feel completely lost in the logic of the following example code:

```
namespace StructInClass
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
            someClass.DoStaff();
        }
    }


    public class SomeClass
    {
        private SomeStruct _someStruct;

        public SomeClass() =>        
            _someStruct = new SomeStruct();  
    
        public void DoStaff() => 
            _someStruct = new SomeStruct(4, 5); 
    }


    public readonly struct SomeStruct
    {
        public readonly int x;
        public readonly int y;

        public SomeStruct()
        {
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = 1;  
        }

        public SomeStruct(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

I have several questions here.

1. Do I correctly understand that when I create an instance of `SomeClass` its `SomeStruct` instance will be placed in Heap (meanwhile pointer for this struct instance lies in Stack)?
2. When I call `someClass.DoStaff()` new instance of `SomeStruct` is created within corresponding stack frame of `DoStuff` method, right? Then pointer now points to new struct instance in Stack?
3. Is there any sense to declare private field of `SomeStruct` type in terms of perfomance?

Googling gives me ambiguous answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1. SomeClass is on the heap, the struct is inline in that heap memory (if SomeStruct was a class then it would be in a separate hea allocation)

#2 no - its on the heap

#3 - yes its inlined in the containing class as opposed to being a new heap allocation

Comment: Thanks! But what if I change my DoStuff method like this: `DoStaff(){SomeStruct s = new(); _struct = s;}`. Does that mean new struct instance will be created in Stack and then copied to Heap inline with SomeClass fields?